# executing a script uploaded through file upload in public folder

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We have to fix some security vulnerability in our system, and one of the items is to: disable execution of uploaded scripts/exe's through file upload control.

We have excel upload facility. Lets say hypothetically hacker changes the .exe to .xls and uploads it (there are ways to block that, but ignore that for now). Also assume that

1. the upload folder is within pubilc directory from where the website is installed in IIS. OR
2. Someone can access that file by specifying a full path of file thru some api endpoint of which hacker is aware of

Now given that there is an exe or a script which is accessible to the hacker through above means, is it possible for hacker to run that script/exe in someway, so that it can cause harm to the server where the site is hosted?

I am not really security expert hence cant think ways how that can be possible? How a hacker can remotely run exe/script on server, given that they does not have any access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the script would require remote access to the server, either directly or by exploiting some bug in the website code (similar to SQL injection). The risk here is mostly in hosting malware, especially if you allow user uploads to be downloaded by other users. While getting malware onto a machine is not as simple as just renaming an executable to another file type (it still has to be run as an executable rather than an Excel spreadsheet, for instance, to be able to function), it is possible to embed malware in various types of files, such that the act of opening that file causes execution of the malware. In that sense, you really can't tell at a glance whether a file is malware or not. It could look like an Excel file even open up properly in Excel, but still wreck havoc. The only way to be safe is scan all user uploaded files with a good antimalware application.

As far as running something remotely goes, though, the access to the server required to run the script would provide a much better avenue for mischief that your upload form, anyways. So anyone who could manage that kind of access isn't going to be trying to exploit you through your upload form, and anyone who uploads something malicious without that access can't really do anything.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great insight on the topic. As i understand, (1) there is no way somebody can remotely execute an exe unless there is a code for it (which we don't have). (2) There is no magical tool hackers has allow them in running a script remotely (i got answer from someone that hackers has great tools, they can do anything) (3) by checking file signature of xls/xlsx i should be able to take care of malware part

Comment: Hackers "hack". That's where the name comes from. In other words, they find and exploit security holes. The point I was making was not that you couldn't be hacked, but rather that the type of exploit needed to run malware that was uploaded though your website UI would give the attacker a better and more efficient vector for compromising your system than actually using the website UI to upload a file. Essentially, if someone has the ability to run executables on your server, you're borked, upload form or not.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that you should definitely do is to remove IIS handlers permissions from running scripts, otherwise anybody can upload a ".asp" or a ".aspx" or any other script engine file and then execute it by requesting it. One simple way to test that is just create a "test.asp" file with "<%= Now() >" and if that returns you the date, then anybody can upload scripts and run them in your server.

The way to disable that in IIS 7+ would be to add a configuration file in a parent directory and edit the permission for handlers, for example assuming a child folder called "public" you can drop the following web.config to disable that:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="public">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers accessPolicy="Read" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

You can test then that it should no longer execute the file and instead block it. If you want to allow download of them, then you'll need to configure the static file handler (and request filtering) to handle everything instead, but make sure you do that for that folder only since you don't want people downloading your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. Btw, if I am not wrong you are talking about `Handler Mappings section -> Script -> Execute` permission should not be set...

Comment: Yes, that is correct, above it is the Handler Mappings, just make sure that when you edit the setting that it is not saved in a web.config inside the public folder in the first place or otherwise somebody could change it if they have write access. That is why I recommend using a location path so that you can save it in the parent (non-public) folder, or could even be inside ApplicationHost.config to be more safe since only Administrators can change that using the right location path.

Comment: great, really nice suggestion and insight. Really thankful. Got to know another way to improve security